# React Native socket.io websocket can't connect if connection drops once

Tags: react-native, websocket, socket.io, engine.io

I am using React Native (0.63.4) and socket.io client (2.4.0) to connect to my socket.io server:

```
 socket = io(MESSENGER_URL, {
            path: "/messenger",
            timeout: 4500,
            forceNew: true,
            transports: ['websocket'],
            transportOptions: {
              polling: {
                extraHeaders: { 'authorization': "Bearer " + accessTokenSelector(store.getState())! }
              },
              websocket: {
                extraHeaders: { 'authorization': "Bearer " + accessTokenSelector(store.getState())! }
              }
            }
        });
```

Everything works fine and stable until connection intermittently drops. Once connection is dropped and Internet connection is established, socket.io gets into this infinite loop:

```
SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/RCTLog.js:47
Error: websocket error
    at WS.Transport.onError (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transport.js:68:13)
    at WebSocket.ws.onerror (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/websocket.js:163:10)
    at WebSocket.dispatchEvent (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:35)
    at /path/to/my/app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/WebSocket.js:260:14
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:189:33)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:416:27)
    at /path/to/my/app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:109:12
    at MessageQueue.__guard (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:9)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (/path/to/my/app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:108:10)
    at /path/to/my/app/.vscode/.react/debuggerWorker.js:199:58 {type: 'TransportError', description: Event, stack: 'Error: websocket error
    at WS.Transport.on…/.vscode/.react/debuggerWorker.js:199:58', message: 'websocket error'}
```

I can't get it to connect unless I *restart* my app (hot reloading also doesn't help). I've tried both `forceNew` set `true` and `false`, doesn't make any difference. If I use `polling` transport instead of `websocket` the problem goes away (connection gets established and working successfully after disconnection/reconnection), but I want to use websockets.

What am I doing wrong? (I can't use v3.x as the server is on 2.x)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having trouble with the same error message: `SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert`

Comment: @James I think there is a problem with the transport options. Try removing the websocket transport option at least to see what happens. it probably messes up as long polling is required before upgrading to websockets. That certificate warning is safe to ignore, it's irrelevant.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu hi did you manage to find a solution, i am running to the same problem. My app stops working when connection drops. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74121600/app-stops-working-when-i-keep-sending-multiple-messages-with-socket-io/

Comment: @kd12345 unfortunately not. that project was halted. but I remember working A LOT, trying every combination, with no avail.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu what is causing it to drop? I dont understand whats happening

Comment: also, when that happens the entire app API requests stop working for some reason